# Pytest mock return value of all object methods

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Is there any way to mock all methods of an object at once (without individually mocking)?

Example:

```py
class MyObj:
    def x():
        ...

    def y():
        ...

    # ...

obj = MyObj()

mock_all(obj, return_value=500)

assert obj.x() == 500
assert obj.y() == 500
```

Comment: Wouldn't be a great test, would it? Just imagine you mixed up `x` and `y` in the code.

Comment: Do you really want all methods of the mocked object to return the same value? What about methods that were not present in the original object before the mock?